# Pandas MuliIndex selection of hierarchical columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, multi-index

Goal: Transform raw data pulled from EuroStat via Pandas DataReader and reshape the data such that it has a Pandas DateTime object as the index and countries across as columns.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web  
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(1900,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()
df2 = web.DataReader('tipsii20', 'eurostat', start = start,end = end)
df2.columns
```

looking at the columns, we can see that we are working with a MultiIndex

> MultiIndex(levels=[[u'Rest of the world'], [u'Net liabilities
>   (liabilities minus assets)'], [u'Net external debt'], [u'Percentage of
>   gross domestic product (GDP)'], [u'Unadjusted data (i.e. neither
>   seasonally adjusted nor calendar adjusted data)'], [u'Austria',
>   u'Belgium', u'Bulgaria', u'Croatia', u'Cyprus', u'Czech Republic',
>   u'Denmark', u'Estonia', u'Finland', u'France', u'Germany (until 1990
>   former territory of the FRG)', u'Greece', u'Hungary', u'Ireland',
>   u'Italy', u'Latvia', u'Lithuania', u'Luxembourg', u'Malta',
>   u'Netherlands', u'Poland', u'Portugal', u'Romania', u'Slovakia',
>   u'Slovenia', u'Spain', u'Sweden', u'United Kingdom'], [u'Annual']],
>              labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 6, 7, 11, 25, 8, 9, 3,
>   12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 26, 24, 23, 27], [0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0]],
>              names=[u'PARTNER', u'STK_FLOW', u'BOP_ITEM', u'UNIT', u'S_ADJ', u'GEO', u'FREQ'])

I would like to transform this dataset so that it maintains its DateTime index, but uses names['GEO'] as the columns. Should this be df2.xs?

Comment: What is `start` and `end` ?

Comment: Thanks, just added the start and end objects

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.DataFrame` with `get_level_values(5)` since GEO is in fifth level for columns incase you want to preserve the dataframe for future reference i.e

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame(df2.values,df2.index,df2.columns.get_level_values(5))
```

Or assign the columns by getting level values like

```
df2.columns =  df2.columns.get_level_values(5)
```

Output :

```
print(ndf.head().iloc[:,:4])

GEO          Austria  Belgium  Bulgaria  Cyprus
TIME_PERIOD                                    
2010-01-01      28.0   -121.2      37.1    70.9
2011-01-01      24.0   -118.8      29.6   127.1
2012-01-01      25.8   -102.7      25.4   137.2
2013-01-01      20.1    -88.4      21.6   140.0
2014-01-01      20.0    -71.1      18.3   136.1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel([0,1,2,3,4,6])
```

Another solution if know level name similar as [Bharath shetty' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46974711/2901002):

```
df2.columns =  df2.columns.get_level_values('GEO')
```

Comment: This is so simple

Comment: I hate the documentation now they say it should be int but can also take strings?

Comment: Yes, it can be string or int, all are valid values.

Comment: It said `int` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html. Can you edit the documentation